# Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: not well-formed

Tags: xml, ubuntu-16.04, ros

I am having an error while trying to run video_file.launch, the file contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
   <!-- launch video stream -->
   <include file="$(find video_stream_opencv)/launch/camera.launch" >
        <!-- node name and ros graph name -->
        <arg name="camera_name" value="videofile" />
        <!-- full path to the video file -->
        <!-- wget http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 -O /tmp/small.mp4 -->
        <arg name="video_stream_provider" value="/tmp/small.mp4" />
        <!-- set camera fps to (video files not affected) -->
        <!-- <arg name="set_camera_fps" value="30"/> -->
        <!-- set buffer queue size of frame capturing to -->
        <arg name="buffer_queue_size" value="1000" />
        <!-- throttling the querying of frames to -->
        <arg name="fps" value="30" />
        <!-- setting frame_id -->
        <arg name="frame_id" value="videofile_frame" />
        <!-- camera info loading, take care as it needs the "file:///" at the start , e.g.:
        "file:///$(find your_camera_package)/config/your_camera.yaml" -->
        <arg name="camera_info_url" value="" />
        <!-- flip the image horizontally (mirror it) -->
        <arg name="flip_horizontal" value="false" />
        <!-- flip the image vertically -->
        <arg name="flip_vertical" value="false" />
        <!-- enable looping playback -->
        <arg name="loop_videofile" value="true" />
        <!-- visualize on an image_view window the stream generated -->
        <arg name="visualize" value="true" />
   </include>
</launch>
```

And this is the error I am getting:

> Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 5

The code is the same as found in :

> https://github.com/ros-drivers/video_stream_opencv

Comment: Try to remove the first line ```    <?xml version="1.0"?>```

Comment: tried removing the first line but still the same issue

Comment: How are you calling the launch file?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to append the `.launch` extension after the file name, as stated in the ROS documentation:

> Many ROS packages come with "launch files", which you can run with:
>
> `roslaunch package_name file.launch`

If the file extension is omitted, the same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

XML does not allow whitespace to appear before the XML declaration (the `<?xml .... ?>` part). Remove this before parsing.

Comment: I removed the whitespace but I am getting the same error.